# Vertica: Create Recursive Function

Tags: function, vertica

I am trying to work around the issue that Vertica's HEX_TO_BINARY function only supports VARCHAR and not LONG VARCHAR.

I am trying to create a recursive SQL function that will solve this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LONG_HEX_TO_BINARY(HEX_VALUE LONG VARCHAR) RETURN LONG VARBINARY
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN (CASE WHEN (LENGTH(HEX_VALUE) > 65000) THEN (HEX_TO_BINARY(CAST(SUBSTR(HEX_VALUE,1,65000) as VARCHAR(65000))) || LONG_HEX_TO_BINARY(SUBSTR(HEX_VALUE,65001))) ELSE HEX_TO_BINARY(CAST(HEX_VALUE AS VARCHAR(65000)))  END);
END;
```

However when I try to compile it (using psql) I get

```
ERROR:  Syntax error at or near "EOL"
```

Using Vertica's vsql client I get

```
ROLLBACK 3457: Function LONG_HEX_TO_BINARY(long varchar) does not exist, or permission is denied for LONG_HEX_TO_BINARY(long varchar) HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts
```

Any ideas, is creating a recursive function even allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work

First create a 'dummy' function to establish the signature

```
dbadmin=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LONG_HEX_TO_BINARY(HEX_VALUE LONG VARCHAR)
dbadmin-> RETURN LONG VARBINARY
dbadmin-> AS
dbadmin-> begin
dbadmin->    return NULL;
dbadmin-> end;
CREATE FUNCTION
dbadmin=> /
```

Now replace it with the real function

```
dbadmin=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LONG_HEX_TO_BINARY(HEX_VALUE LONG VARCHAR)
dbadmin-> RETURN LONG VARBINARY
dbadmin-> AS
dbadmin-> BEGIN
dbadmin->    RETURN (
dbadmin(>      CASE
dbadmin(>        WHEN (LENGTH(HEX_VALUE) > 65000) THEN
dbadmin(>      (HEX_TO_BINARY(CAST(SUBSTR(HEX_VALUE,1,65000) as VARCHAR(65000))) || LONG_HEX_TO_BINARY(SUBSTR(HEX_VALUE,65001)))
dbadmin(>        ELSE
dbadmin(>  HEX_TO_BINARY(CAST(HEX_VALUE AS VARCHAR(65000)))
dbadmin(>   END
dbadmin(> );
dbadmin-> END;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Now to see if it actually works..